# Is it possible to create a new table by joining existing two athena tables in AWS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have two different tables A and B with its own schema structure whose data comes from a s3 bucket location. I would like to join the table and create a new table in athena.
Is this possible in AWS Athena?

Comment: as [`create table as select ...`, `create view` isn't supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html) at this time, i don't think your request is possible.

Comment: It is supported now